# Plotting histogram using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, histogram

This is the graph that I am unable to plot in matplotlib using python.

[image: this is the graph that I am unable to plot in matplotlib using python. help me please]

How could I plot such plot?

Comment: click that to view tha image

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n, bins, params = plt.hist(arrival_delay)
```

Assuming the data you want to histogram is stored in `arrival delay`. Read [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) documentation for more info.